# Convert PFObject to NSString in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

the problem was getting the Comments for Feeds that are stored in different Classes on Parse, the actual Problem is getting the body out of the class as String.

I always get an error saying "PFObject is not a subtype of NSString"

```
var Comments = [PFObject]() 



var FeedObjects = self.Feeds[indexPath.row]
var CommentObjects = Comments

    var queryComment = PFQuery(className:"Comment")
        queryComment.whereKey("post", equalTo: FeedObjects)
        queryComment.selectKeys(["body", "author"])
        queryComment.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        queryComment.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
           if error == nil {
              var Comments = objects as [PFObject]
             self.Comments = Comments
  }
}
            println(Comments)
```

The output at this stage is

```
[<Comment: 0x7ffa98f2a560, objectId: efB384DliK, localId: (null)> {
    author = test;
    body = test;
}]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code of the table view is actually not relevant to your problem, is it? Try to narrow down your question, so that people can get what your question is faster.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Here nowhere. When i set var Comment = CommentObjects["body"] as String!   For example

Comment: This won't work. `CommentsObjects` is a `PFObject` array. I think you should clean it up a little before trying to fix this (e.g. more speaking variable names, don't criss-cross assign variables etc.). It looks a little messed up to be honest.

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I get home. Dont really understand what you directly mean but let's see maybe I'll get it after work. Du sagst das alles so leicht ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer your question. The error you get is actually self-explanatory. You are trying to convert a `PFObject` to an `NSString`, which of course will not work.

The error occurs when you call

```
var Comment = CommentObjects["body"] as String!
```

as you mentioned. This happens because you define `CommentObjects` like this:

```
var CommentObjects = Comments
```

and `Comments` is

```
var Comments = [PFObject]()
```

This a) does not make much sense and b) causes your error, because `CommentObjects` is actually an array of `PFObjects` and thus `CommentObjects["body"]` returns a `PFObject` which you are trying to convert to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sebastian, this is what I have now..

```
var selectedFeed: PFObject!
```

at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I set this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var FeedObjects = self.Feeds[indexPath.row]
        self.selectedFeed = FeedObjects...
```

created an `func` for retrieving the Comments for the selected Row.

```
func retrieveComments() {
        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        var queryComment = PFQuery(className:"Comment")
        queryComment.whereKey("post", equalTo: selectedFeed)
        queryComment.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        queryComment.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (comments:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for comment in comments {
                    var commentBody = comment["body"] as String
                    var commentAuthor = comment["author"] as String
                    var commentDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(comment.createdAt)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and when the `showDetailsViewController` appears `retrieveComments()` is called.

It works =) Sorry for wasting your Time..